# I keep receiving "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Script" error message even after I deleted all script for my google forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently attempted to use script in GoogleForms to have all results emailed to my account and it didn't work and sent me error emails constantly. So I deleted all script, created new spreadsheets for all GoogleForms I'd created, and I am STILL receiving these error emails...

Looks like this:
**Your script, Script, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

Summary:
Error Message   Count
No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 20, file "Code")    24
Details:
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
5/7/13 9:45 PM  sendFormByEmail No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 20, file "Code")    time-based  5/7/13 9:45 PM**

I've checked in the script editor and such to see if there was anything, but there is nothing. I am really frustrated as this is a work account and I receive tons of these emails.

I'd appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try "Resources / All your triggers" inside the editor? Your unwanted triggers might be visible there, but maybe not if they're deleted. If your scripts are still in your trash, you can try restoring them and then deleting the triggers. Beyond that, this is a long-known and still unaddressed issue. (Sorry, I'm not about to experiment with it myself - I don't want the headache if that goes badly.)

[Issue 143](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=143): Spreadsheets with time triggered scripts should no longer trigger when spreadsheet is deleted

Comment: When I go to "Script Editor" it brings me to an "Untitled Project," where I *had* created script for email forwarding and deleted after it just crapped out. I continue to receive emails so I deleted all spreadsheets and recreated new ones for the forms I'd created.

Honestly, I think it came down to the fact that the spreadsheets were still in my "Trash." I've deleted them and I am going to wait and see if I still receive emails... it's gotta be that as there is nothing in my script editor to work with!

Answer (score 0):

In the spreadsheet, just go to the Tools> Script Editor.

Then the new window should open and in that go to the Edit> All your Triggers.

Then click on the notifications link, and remove your email id.

Hope this helps someone.