# Can't turn off a deleted Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I had a script a couple years back set on a time-based trigger to monitor a page. After things were working correctly I deleted the script, but about once a month I still get a failure notice from Google that the script didn't run correctly. How can I turn off the triggers? The emails the systems send me has a link to manage triggers that ends in a 403 Forbidden, and I've checked under **Resources > All your triggers** but it says I have no triggers set up.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462899/i-keep-receiving-summary-of-failures-for-google-apps-script-script-error-mess

Comment: Check https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list for similar issues

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem a few years ago. I'm convinced it's a bug on Google's side, but the workaround was so easy that I didn't bother looking up if it had been reported.

All I had to do to fix this was find the Script in the trash, take it out of the trash, manually delete that trigger, and delete the file again. Yeah, it's kind of annoying and you'd think triggers would stop when it's deleted, but apparently not. Hope that works well for you!

Also, make sure that the user who does this is the same as the user who set up the trigger =)

Comment: Where is the trash? If you mean in Google drive, then my script is long gone as I deleted it shortly after things were working and I've emptied the trash in there many times since. If there a Scripts trash I'm unsure of where to find that.

Comment: Yes, I meant the Google Drive trash (not a special Scripts trash). I'm honestly not sure what the workaround is if you can't restore it. Unfortunately, this might have to be reported to Google. That sucks, I'm sorry =(