# Remove Time Trigger Of Deleted Sheet - GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, v8

I deployed several Sheets AddOns at the Google Marketplace. Those AddOns allow the user to perform daily up-/downloads automatically. Creating and deleting the time trigger works smoothly without any issue.

In case the user deleted the sheet entirely and did not perform the manual deletion of the time trigger, I run into a problem.

In "runtimeVersion": "V8" I receive following error at following code:

```
var ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

> Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because
> you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access
> it.

Therefore I can't load (hence delete) the trigger associated with this sheet:

```
ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ActiveSpreadSheet)
```

Does anyone know how I can figure out the trigger ID(s) of deleted Sheets at "runtimeVersion": "V8"?
(in V5 this is working)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to delete a Spreadsheet trigger of a spreadsheet that was deleted, so you could use try...catch to handle the error.

Related

- [I keep receiving "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Script" error message even after I deleted all script for my google forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16462899/1595451)

Comment: The amount of triggers per script is limited to 20. As my AddOns allow to use them in multiple spreadsheets, I want to delete those "sheetless"-trigger. 
I could retrieve all project triggers of this user, as ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() is still working, but I do not want to delete triggers of other sheets